# How do i add Microsoft Accounts to my Azure AD using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-active-directory

I can add new users to my AD using Command:

```
New-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $signInAddress -FirstName $firstName -LastName $lastName -DisplayName $displayname -Title $title
```

but it requires the UPN to be in my AD domain.

I see related questions about adding accounts from other Azure AD (and currently that is not supported).

Answer (score 0):

Henrik, Azure AD PowerShell doesn't support adding Microsoft Accounts to the directory. It can only be done using the Azure Management portal.